# Insert or Update without a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, insert-update

I have table with two columns:

```
ItemMaster (Item INT, Quantity INT)
```

If an item is already there, then I should update the Quantity.  Otherwise, I have to insert a Record in this table.

Is this possible without Loop?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: one possibility to right 2 different queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done without a loop yes:

```
UPDATE table1
SET Quantity = Quantity + 1
WHERE Item = @itemID

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    INSERT INTO table1 (Item, Quantity)
    VALUES (@itemID, 1)
```

Comment: You are right but for your answer i have to use the loop of all the item and process one by one item than it is possible.

Comment: My answer doesn't involve any loops. You might need to edit your question if there's another requirement here somewhere.

Comment: yes but for that you have to use IN clause like that WHERE ITEMID IN (Select ItemID from ITEMMASTER)

Answer (score 1):

FOR one row

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * from ItemMaster WHERE Item = @Item)
    UPDATE ItemMaster
      SET Quantity = @Quantity
    WHERE Item = @Item
 ELSE
    INSERT INTO ItemMaster VALUES(@Item, @Quantity)
```

For many rows:

```
 INSERT INTO ItemMaster (Item, Quantity)
 SELECT Item, Quantity
 FROM AnotherTable a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from ItemMaster i Where i.Item = a.Item);

 UPDATE ItemMaster i
    SET Quantity = a.Quantity
 FROM AnotherTable a
 WHERE a.Item = i.Item
```